# Unable to stop WPF storyboard declared in XAML from calling Render()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF storyboard defined in my App.xaml as such:

```
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyPath}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl},Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="InnerSpinnerBeginStoryboard">
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="180"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>  
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="InnerSpinnerBeginStoryboard"/>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
```

Unfortunately, triggering `RemoveStoryboard` does not seem to stop the storyboard from calling Render() after the `ExitAction` is triggered, which eats up the UI thread unnecessarily and slows down the application.

I verified that this was being caused by `RepeatBehavior` by trying `"30x"` instead of `"Forever"` and indeed the calls to Render() do stop once the 30 repeats have been completed.

Does anyone know how I can force the storyboard to actually stop calling Render() once `RepeatBehavior` is turned on?

Comment: You can try to use `SkipStoryboardToFill` instead of `RemoveStoryboard`.

Comment: Or use `StopStoryboad` before removing it

Comment: Neither of those suggestions seem to work unfortunately :(